# I need help understanding JavaScript "strict mode"

Tags: javascript, jquery, visual-studio, strict-mode

I'm writing a lot more JavaScript these days than I used to.  I'm writing a bunch of JavaScript libraries for our product.  Wanting to be as careful as possible I'm doing full jsdoc comments, etc. I also have 'use strict'; in all of my libraries and functions.

We're using jQuery and Kendo UI (no comments about whether these are good, bad, or indifferent, that ship has sailed).  Both of these libraries have globals that they create, at the least "$" and "kendo" for each respectively.  I'm using Visual Studio with Resharper so I get lots of help writing the JavaScript.

Now, here's my confusion.  In my libraries, which are in files like LibraryName.js, I have to use both jQuery functions and kendo functions, so I'm doing things like $.ready(...) and kendo.keys.SPACEBAR.  Visual studio gives me grief over "kendo" not being defined in strict mode, and it gives me grief about $.ready not being defined, but it doesn't give me grief over $ not being defined?  Why is it special?

I know, this is a small thing, but I really want to understand what strict mode means and what the limitations are.

Thanks for reading!

Addition: Apparently I'm not being clear, so I'll try to expand.  In strict mode, "...you can not, for example, use undeclared variables."  Well, I don't see how one library file (say, mySuperLibrary.js) can use global values from another library file (jQuery or Kendo UI) without using "undeclared variables" as $ is a variable containing a function and kendo is as well.  Neither of these are declared in my script, obviously.

What then confuses me is that Resharper complains that for $.ready, it flags "ready" as being undeclared but doesn't say $ is undeclared.  It also flags kendo as being undeclared.  The warning it gives me is "Using a variable (property or object) without declaring it is not allowed in 'strict mode'".

Now, my library works fine.  It goes ahead and uses these "undeclared variables" to solve the problems it needs to solve.  By the time my library loads these variables are declared.

In any other language I would somehow document in the file what external globals I require to be defined.  I don't see any way to do that in JavaScript.  There isn't any kind of "import" or "external requirements".  I guess I'm wondering if I'm just missing something.  There is no way to stop it from bugging me (so maybe the problem is my ocd, not wanting my libraries to have "fake" errors).

Comment: Googling *javascript strict mode* turns up https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Strict_mode and https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_strict.asp What specifically don't those explain?

Comment: Strict mode has nothing to do with globals being defined; VS just isn’t aware of your globals. You should probably edit your question to ask how to get it to become aware of scripts you’re including instead.

Comment: In Visual Studio you can use a reference directive to make IntelliSense aware of other scripts: `/// <reference path="some.library.js" />`

Comment: @MichaelLiu That is fantastic, works great, thank you.